# Логика в LINQ запросах

Tags: c#, linq

Можно сделать проверку переменной на `null` в LINQ запросе? Если переменная равна `NULL` то `where` не производит фильтрацию.

```
var select = from p in db.Products
             where p.Vendor == vendorId
             select p;
```

где `vendorId` зависит от выбора пользователя, и если он не выбрал ничего, тогда возвращается весь список.

проверять через `if` не подходит, потому что могут быть разные варианты запросов на выборку.

Comment: Честно говоря, я так и не понял, почему нельзя проверять через `if`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var select = from p in db.Products
             where vendorId == null || p.Vendor == vendorId
             select p;
```